# Is it necessary to define Referential Actions in SQLAlchemy's Model-Definitions, although they are defined inside InnoDB-Table?

Tags: python, mysql, model, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy

I have several MySQL InnoDB tables (`authors, books, countrys`) in a Database and they are all linked by an `association_table` which looks like this:

```
id, fk_author_id, fk_book_id, fk_country_id
```

I have defined some Referential Actions for the foreignkeys (fk_). Do I have to define the same referencial Actions within the Model-Definitions in SQLAlchemy, or does SQLAlchemy collect this information while reflecting?